# Can the new 2016 MacBook Pro 13" without Touch Bar drive a 4K display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, thunderbolt, 4k

I currently have an old MacBook Pro 15" Retina from 2012, driving two monitors, a 24" 4K monitor and a 21.5" 1080p monitor.

This setup works, except for one catch - the 4k monitor refreshes at 30Hz, which makes it a bit laggy.

I was thinking of getting the new MacBook Pro 13" base model with 2 Thunderbolt/USB-C ports. Since I have 2 external monitors I figure I need the USB-C to Power + USB + USB-C adapter too.

Given I get these, will I be able to now drive my primary 4K display at 60Hz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the *Video Support* section of the [Tech Specs](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/) for the 2016 13" MacBook Pro:

> **Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display at millions of colors and:**
>
> One display with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion
>   colors
>
> Up to two displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at over a
>   billion colors
>
> **Thunderbolt 3 digital video output**
>
> Native DisplayPort output over USB‑C
>
> VGA, HDMI, and Thunderbolt 2 output supported using adapters (sold
>   separately)

Comment: Does this still apply when using the adapter? I suppose 1 port could natively connect to and drive the 4k display, and the other one could run into the USB/Power/1080p-digital-display adapter, but thought I'd check.

Comment: @Gaurav Sharma, There are just too may adapters and more coming as a result of the new MacBook Pro for me to comment beyond saying I would think you need to check the Tech Specs of any adapter you use to insure it can handed the desired input/output once the adapter is in place. As an example I know some adapters max on the video will be 30Hz and some will be 60Hz, so obviously you'll need to choose the adapter that outputs 60Hz, etc. Just don't buy any adapters that you can't get full and detailed specs on.